# oversubscribed literal/length tree error while creating database

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle9i, oracleforms

While running **database configuration assistant(oracle 9i)** I get error **oversubscribed literal/length tree**.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance of `java.util.zip.ZipException`.  There are a number of things which might cause it.  One cause is the executed path being too long, for instance if you extracted the zip to a sub-directory (instead of, say, the root).

But there are a number of other things which might cause it, e.g. file corruption.  So if the directory path length is not the problem you will need to give us more details.  For instance, what OS are you installing on?   Also, is there any more info regarding the error in the log file: `$ORACLE_HOME/assistants/opca/install.log`?

Comment: Thanks for the response..
I was trying to install oracle 9i on windows XP. I found DBCA error log which says..

Fatal NI connect error 12560, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=BEQ)(PROGRAM=oracle)(ARGV0=oracleorcl)(ARGS='(DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))'))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=j:\ora9i_install\bin\sqlplus.exe)(HOST=BNS)(USER=invincible))))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
 TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 9.2.0.1.0 - Production
 Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: 
  
Tracing not turned on.